# loop using batch until any key is pressed

Tags: loops, batch-file

I recently made this little code.

```
@echo off
mode 1000
set /A x=0
:loop
timeout /T 1 > Nul /nobreak
set /A x=x+1
echo %X%
goto loop
```

Can someone please help me and edit this code, that it loops, until any key is pressed and then stops the loop? Im new in coding using Batch and therefore dont know how to do it :(

Comment: To begin with  your second line should really use the recommended syntax, and I'd also advise that you do not ask for `1000` columns. `%SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com CON: COLS=c LINES=n`. Your third line should not use the `/A`rithmetic option, at all, `Set "x=0"`, your fourth line should read as `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NoBreak 1>NUL`. Your fifth line should read as `Set /A x += 1`, and please don't change the case of your variable, so line six should read as `Echo(%x%`. As for your question, you need to explain to us exactly what you want the code to do when a key is pressed.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope you can understand it better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `choice` approach ([see Mofi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71616241/2152082)) was my first idea too, but it contradicts your "any key" demand.

Therefore I use a different approach: start another instance in the background, which just waits for a key (`pause`) and then creates a file.
The main loop exits, once the file exists.

```
@echo off 
setlocal
start /b cmd /c "pause >nul & break>flag"
del flag >nul 2>&1
:loop
if exist flag goto :done
timeout 1 >nul
set /a count+=1
echo %count%
goto :loop
:done
del flag >nul 2>&1
echo interrupted by a key press.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the /nobreak should help

Comment: Nope - that wouldn't break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Awaiting a key press while other activities are ongoing is not that trivial in batch scripting.

However, here is a imperfect but quite simple semi-solution using [`choice`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) and [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html):

```cmd
@echo off
set /A "X=0"
:LOOP
rem /* `choice is utilised; all (case-insensitive) letter and numeral keys (excluding
rem    key `0`) are defined to quit the loop; `choice` features a timeout, upon which
rem    the default choice (key `0` here) is taken: */
choice /C abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 /T 1 /D 0 > nul
rem /* `choice` reflects the actually pressed key in the `ErrorLevel` value, meaning
rem    `ErrorLevel = 1` reflects the first key `a`, and `ErrorLevel = 36` reflects
rem    the last one in the list, `0`; since the default choice after the timeout is
rem    `0`, pressing the `0` key has got the same effect as not pressing any key: */
if ErrorLevel 1 if not ErrorLevel 36 goto :QUIT
set /A "X+=1"
echo %X%
goto :LOOP
:QUIT
```